# Returning 'java.lang.NullPointerException1' when trying to activate a billing payment with paypal

Tags: php, curl, paypal

Hi I'm trying to activate my paypal billing plan with PHP Curl but I keep getting 'java.lang.NullPointerException1' returned

Here's my code

```
    curl_init($ch);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PATCH');
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $resultTwo = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: why are you getting java error messages?

Comment: That's why I'm confused, I'm only using PHP

Comment: It points to 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-plans/'.$planID where planID is the id returned when I created the billing plan

Comment: $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-plans/".$planID);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, false);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PATCH');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
  $result = curl_exec($ch);

Comment: I get HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error Server: returned using the above code

Comment: Sorted it, thanks Dagon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely you're seeing a bug in the PayPal Sandbox backend. Please submit it to [merchant support](https://www.paypal.com/mts) and include the full response, including the `Debug-Id` header.

Answer (score 0):

Read documentation carefully.
cURL sends data with POST method as default, but [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-plans#plan_get) says, you shoud use GET.

---

Solution is:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
```